# Snowflake LIMIT/OFFSET performance issues

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm processing a 260M row, ~1,500 column table in chunks through a model in Python. Using the connectors, I grab a chunk of 100,000 records each time. I'm using LIMIT and OFFSET to churn through the table. After each section I increase the OFFSET by the chunksize. As the OFFSET increases, the time the query runs increases to the point where each chunk takes me in excess of 45 minutes to grab toward the end. Here is a mock up of my query:

```
SELECT ~50_fields
FROM mytable
WHERE a_couple_conditions
ORDER BY my_primary_key
LIMIT 100000 OFFSET #########
```

Given the performance this is a particularly bad way to run this. I read that I might be able to use RESULT_SCAN to speed it up, but the docs said that I would still need to use ORDER BY against it, which seems to me may defeat the purpose. I actually don't care what order the records come into my process, just that I process each row exactly once.

Is there a way to get these queries running in a decent amount of time, of should I look into doing something like increasing the LIMIT dramatically for each chunk, then breaking it down further in my program? Any ideas or best practices on getting Snowflake to play ball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you tried something like this?

```
SELECT ~50_fields, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY my_primary_key) as row_cnt
FROM mytable
WHERE a_couple_conditions;
```

and then loop through:

```
SELECT ~50_fields
FROM table(result_scan(query_id))
WHERE row_cnt BETWEEN x and xx;
```

where query_id is the query_id from the first statement.  The initial select might take a long time to order the entire table, but the remaining chunks should be very quick and will not take longer and longer as you go.

Comment: I wonder if row_cnt is redundant to primary key, and whether he could just keep track of the primary key on the Python side and use that in the where.

Comment: I was assuming that his process required an exact number of records in each batch, but perhaps that isn't the case and he could do what you're suggesting.  My solution gives the same size batch every time until the last batch.

Comment: Also, if the primary key isn't clustered, then he'd be scanning a lot of records each time to try and get the numbers.  This method would likely perform better, since it's using result cache.

Comment: Seems like the same code that's keeping track of the offset, could read the primary key of the last record then use that in the WHERE with a LIMIT to get a fixed size, but I am just speculating.  Also what do you think about the performance of Snowflake compared to exporting to disk for this `select * from blah` type usecase

Comment: @NatTaylor But then you'd need to go back and find the max of the primary key from that recordset to figure out where to start the next one.  Pretty sure that wouldn't be as efficient.  Having the full recordset in result cache would be very efficient.  Typically, I prefer exporting data to S3, but that isn't local disk, and the OP didn't really specify where the python was running.  It might not be efficient to get it loaded into the python module that he is running.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. This solution works well, I was running into >45min on data chunk pulls for records far into the dataset, with this strategy even the pulls deep into the data take <3min. I clustered on my primary key, so the original query is running in only 5-6min. I believe this solution will meet my performance needs and I'm going to code it into my system. Writing the query result to S3 and then reading it back from there hadn't occurred to me, but if I run into issues with this solution then that will be my next step. Thanks for the helpful assistance!

Comment: Better yet, you can do `select * exclude row_cnt` instead of naming all 50 fields.

Answer (score 0):

All Python SQL clients that I'm aware of allow you to process the output of a query in batches. As an example, here's how `snowflake-connector-python` allows to [retrieve result batches from a query](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-distributed-fetch.html):

```
with connect(...) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        # Execute a query.
        cur.execute('select seq4() as n from table(generator(rowcount => 100000));')

        # Iterate over a list of PyArrow tables for result batches.
        for table_for_batch in cur.fetch_arrow_batches():
          my_pyarrow_table_processing_function(table_for_batch)
```

With Snowflake in particular, the batch size can be controlled in megabytes (but not in rows, sadly) using the parameter [CLIENT_RESULT_CHUNK_SIZE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#client-result-chunk-size).